# Вводные слова или нет

Tags: вводные-слова

**Веру прежде всего; веру в нечто незыблемое, вечное, в истину(?) одним словом(?)  в истину, находящуюся вне отдельного человека.**

Вопрос: почему ставится именно запятая (указано в источнике)? Ведь в том же предложении есть вводные слова "прежде всего", а после них повторяющееся существительное "веру", т. е. так же как и в следующем случае.

P.S. Киньте, пожалуйста, правила постановки точки с запятой в предложении.

Comment: Бека, не знаю, в каком смысле "кинуть", но было бы неплохо, если бы Вы аккуратней оформляли Ваши вопросы (ведь это сайт русского языка). Я исправил, что мог.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Прежде всего" здесь не вводное сочетание. А "одним словом" – вводное. А строгих правил постановки точки с запятой не существует. Грубо говоря, этот знак ставится, когда запятой мало, а точки много.
Надо у автора спросить, почему у него на месте первого вопросительного знака запятая. Гораздо лучше точку с запятой поставить или даже точку.

Answer (score 3):

**Полный текст:** Повторяем: что выражает собою Дон-Кихот?  Веру прежде всего; веру (1) в нечто вечное, незыблемое, (2) в истину, одним словом, (3) в истину, находящуюся вне отдельного человека, но легко ему дающуюся, требующую служения и жертв, но доступную постоянству служения и силе жертвы (И.С. Тургенев).

Веру прежде всего: **прежде всего — наречие**.

Далее  сущ. "веру" управляет   **однородным рядом**:  в нечто, в истину, в истину, причем каждый член ряда является распространенным.

Одним словом — **вводное слово**.

**Точка с запятой** [Розенталь. Указатель слов к разделу «Пунктуация»](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=3403).

Распространенные однородные члены предложения, особенно если внутри них имеются запятые, могут разделяться точкой с запятой.